# Return count 0 with mysql group by and where by date

Tags: mysql

I want to create a single query to result data like this:

[image]

but when I insert `where` clause, column `name` just result a few value from column `m_ccode`:

[image]

Q: how keep all `name` column values if I insert `where` clause?

Here the working fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/687776/10

Comment: Not sure what you need but i geuss you have to make a calendar table or SQL generator that generates a data range looking into the sqlfiddle example.. Question is a bit unclear without expected results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `MONTH(t.date) = '10' AND YEAR(t.date) = '2018'` condition in on cluase like below

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/687776/4)

```
SELECT ccode.name,IFNULL(count(DISTINCT u.username),0) as total_active
,(count(DISTINCT u.username) - count(DISTINCT t.username)) as total_non_active
from m_ccode as ccode
left join m_user as u on u.ccode = ccode.id
left join t_safety_act t on t.username = u.username
and MONTH(t.date) = '10' AND YEAR(t.date) = '2018' group by ccode.id;
```

Comment: To keep it ANSI SQL it needs to be `group by ccode.name;` instead off `group by ccode.id;` most likly the database could get the correct data for the column `ccode.name` well grouping with  MySQL's extended GROUP BY feature with functional dependency which the modern MySQL versions support